# Moq - verify returns zero even though I can see the methods being called

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to verify that two methods get called only once, but I keep being told by mock that the actual times they were called was zero:

```
Moq.MockException: 
Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: x => x.Map(.OrderType)
No setups configured.
No invocations performed.
   at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1 setups, IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times, Int32 callCount)
   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
   at Moq.Mock.Verify[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify[TResult](Expression`1 expression, Times times)
   at Ylp.Import.Sandwell.Tests.Factories.SandwellOperatingHoursFactoryTests.WhenInputValid.CallsRestrictionTypeMapper()
```

code:

```
class SandwellOperatingHoursFactoryTestBase
    {
        protected OperatingHoursCms OperatingHoursCms;
        protected virtual Mock<IMap<string, RuleTimeCms>> RuleTimeMapperMock => new Mock<IMap<string, RuleTimeCms>>();
        protected virtual Mock<IMap<string, UkRestrictionTypes.Entry>> RestrictionTypeMapperMock => new Mock<IMap<string, UkRestrictionTypes.Entry>>();

        protected virtual string OrderType => null;
        protected virtual string TimesOfEnforcement => null;

        protected RuleTimeCms ReturnedRuleTimeCms => null;
        protected UkRestrictionTypes.Entry ReturnedRestrictionTypeEntry => null;

    }

    internal class SandwellOperatingHoursFactoryCreateTestBase: SandwellOperatingHoursFactoryTestBase
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            RestrictionTypeMapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map(OrderType)).Returns(ReturnedRestrictionTypeEntry);
            RuleTimeMapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map(TimesOfEnforcement)).Returns(ReturnedRuleTimeCms);


            OperatingHoursCms = new SandwellOperatingHoursFactory(RuleTimeMapperMock.Object,RestrictionTypeMapperMock.Object).Create(OrderType,TimesOfEnforcement);
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    internal class WhenInputValid: SandwellOperatingHoursFactoryCreateTestBase
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CallsRuleTimeMapper()
        {
            RuleTimeMapperMock.Verify(x=>x.Map(TimesOfEnforcement),Times.Once);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CallsRestrictionTypeMapper()
        {
            RestrictionTypeMapperMock.Verify(x => x.Map(OrderType), Times.Exactly(1));
        }
    }

    class SandwellOperatingHoursFactory
    {
        private IMap<string, RuleTimeCms> _ruleTimeMapper;
        private IMap<string, UkRestrictionTypes.Entry> _restrictionTypeMapper;
        internal SandwellOperatingHoursFactory(
            IMap<string, RuleTimeCms> ruleTimeMapper, 
            IMap<string, UkRestrictionTypes.Entry> restrictionTypeMapper)
        {
            _ruleTimeMapper = ruleTimeMapper;
            _restrictionTypeMapper = restrictionTypeMapper;
        }

        public OperatingHoursCms Create(string orderType, string timesOfEnforcement)
        {
            var ruleTime = _ruleTimeMapper.Map(timesOfEnforcement);
            var restrictionType = _restrictionTypeMapper.Map(orderType);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the `Create` method, when executing the line `var restrictionType = _restrictionTypeMapper.Map(orderType);` what is the value of `orderType` is it null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
protected virtual Mock<IMap<string, UkRestrictionTypes.Entry>> RestrictionTypeMapperMock
  => new Mock<IMap<string, UkRestrictionTypes.Entry>>();
```

Is that arrow `=>` there new C# 6 syntax for a property `get` accessor?

Will your property return a ***new*** `Mock<>` each time the `get` accessor runs?

If the answers to my questions are "yes", you will `Setup` one instance of `Mock<>`, then get `.Object` on *another* instance (you use non-strict mocks, so methods like `Map` can be called even if no setup were made on that instance number two). Then finally, on a *third* instance of `Mock<>`, one which has never been used, you call `Verify` to see if method was used.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the value with which you do your setup is not matching the value with which you actually call it.

try replacing

```
 RestrictionTypeMapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map(OrderType)).Returns(ReturnedRestrictionTypeEntry);
```

with

```
 RestrictionTypeMapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(ReturnedRestrictionTypeEntry);
```